# How to redirect from a html page to a another html page which is on local disk

Tags: html, apache

I am creating an appraisal application to accept apraisal for employees and store in the backend, The first page is a login page ,If user has successfully logged in it should redirect to another page which shows employees information but the catch here is that both pages are on local system ,as the browser runs in sandbox mode window.location is not working,I have tried many other similar options but still it doesn't work,I want to know can I use apache or some other server for this purpose.If yes what would be the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta-refresh keyword and supply a path.

> somebody add an example, don't have one

Answer (score 0):

I tried window.location.href() and got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example redirection with meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://bing.com/'" />
```